# What are the Azure IAM permissions for storage account lifecycle policy management to work?

Tags: azure, storage, lifecycle, policy, identity-management

Added a policy in my test subscription and it works as expected.
The same policy at my PROD sub work does not do anything, it should move blobs to the cool access tier from hot.
On my test sub I have owner rights and storage blob data contributor rights.
On my PROD sub I have storage account contributor and storage blob data owner, should I also add storage blob data contributor rights?. Wouldn't that be included in storage account contributor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In order to work with **Azure Storage Account** Life Cycle Management policies, you need role that includes **`Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/managementPolicies/write`** permission.

The valid roles that allow you to work with Life Cycle Management policies are:

- **Owner** - It grants you full access to manage all resources along with assigning roles.
- **Contributor** - It won't allow you to assign roles but grants full access to manage all resources.
- **Storage Account Contributor** - It grants you full access to manage storage accounts(only).

As your **`Test`** subscription has **Owner** rights, it allowed you to manage Life Cycle Management policies.

To confirm this, click on the role and check for storage management policies:

[image]

There is no need to assign **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role to **`Prod`** subscription as it already has **Storage Account Contributor** role that includes below actions:

[image]

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment by assigning ***Storage Account Contributor*** role and got below results.

I created a Life Cycle Management policy to move blobs to the **cool** access tier from **hot** tier like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Storage Accounts -> Your account -> Lifecycle management -> Add a role***

[image]

When I checked the blobs, they are still in **`Hot`** access tier like below:

[image]

As I created the policy recently, it may take upto **48 hrs** to be effective as mentioned below:

[image]

If that's your case, please wait for intended time period and check after a couple of days.

Blobs moved to **`cool`** access tier from **hot** when I checked after a few days like below:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Please check the below note from this **[Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-policy-configure?tabs=azure-portal#code-view:%7E:text=If%20you%20enable%20firewall%20rules%20for%20your%20storage%20account%2C%20lifecycle%20management%20requests%20may%20be%20blocked.)** that confirms management policies will be blocked if firewall rules are enabled for your storage account.

[image]

You need to select exception as below that allows access to trusted Azure services:

[image]

**References:**

[Grant access to trusted azure services | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal#grant-access-to-trusted-azure-services)

[Managing the lifecycle policies - Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/lifecycle-management-overview#i-created-a-new-policy-why-do-the-actions-not-run-immediately)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I have those permission set properly as you mention in your message. Would it be possible that a Networking Firewall rule is affecting this  process? I have checked the box "Enabled from Selected virtual Networks and IP addresses" and under Exceptions, no exceptions are selected like Azure Services.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Please check the updated answer